# How to concatenate year Month name day in sql server

Tags: sql-server

We are getting month name based on month number

```
Declare @mth smallint=1
select DateName(mm,DateAdd(mm,@mth,-1)) as MonthName
```

How to get a date format like  `2017-January-26(year-MonthName-Day)` in SQL Server?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?  Where do you get the year and day values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a date (`@d`):

```
declare @d date = GETDATE();
select cast(YEAR(@d) as varchar(4)) + '-' + DATENAME(mm, @d) + '-' + cast(DAY(@d) as varchar(2))
```

This produces (on a german locale)

```
2017-Juni-27
```

If you have single values for day, month and year insert them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

this gets the date with month as a whole name

```
select replace(convert(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '-')   --you may replace getdate() with your date column
```

you can try this as well :::

```
select cast(year(getdate() )as varchar(5)) + '-' + cast(datename(MONTH,GETDATE()) as varchar(12)) + '-' + cast(DAY(GETDATE()) as varchar(2))
```

Comment: output: 27 Jun 2017

Comment: Not with GetDate() , I have getting  Year int =2017,

Comment: and MonName=Jan, Day =26

Comment: then Concate like 2017-Jan-26

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),126)
```

Output:

> 2017-06-27

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function, with the help of this function you can format date in any format.

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[fn_FormatDate]
(
 @Date   DateTime       --Date value to be formatted
 ,@Format VarChar(40)   --Format to apply
)
Returns VarChar(40)
As
Begin

     -- Insert Day:
     Set @Format = Replace (@Format , 'DDDD' , DateName(Weekday , @Date)) 
     Set @Format = Replace (@Format , 'DDD' , Convert(Char(3),DateName(Weekday , @Date)))
     Set @Format = Replace (@Format , 'DD' , Right(Convert(Char(6) , @Date,12) , 2))
     Set @Format = Replace (@Format , 'D1' , Convert(VarChar(2) , Convert(Integer , Right(Convert(Char(6) , @Date , 12) , 2))))

     -- Insert Month:
     Set @Format = Replace (@Format , 'MMMM', DateName(Month , @Date))
     Set @Format = Replace (@Format , 'MMM', Convert(Char(3) , DateName(Month , @Date)))
     Set @Format = Replace (@Format , 'MM',Right(Convert(Char(4) , @Date,12),2))
     Set @Format = Replace (@Format , 'M1',Convert(VarChar(2) , Convert(Integer , Right(Convert(Char(4) , @Date,12),2))))

     -- Insert the Year:
     Set @Format = Replace (@Format,'YYYY' , Convert(Char(4) , @Date , 112))
     Set @Format = Replace (@Format,'YY' , Convert(Char(2) , @Date , 12))

     -- Insert the Time
     Set @Format = Replace (@Format,'HH' , Convert(Char(5) , @Date , 114))
     Set @Format = Replace (@Format,'hh' , Convert(Char(2) , @Date , 14))

     -- Insert the AM/PM:
     Set @Format = Replace (@Format,'AM/PM' , RIGHT(CONVERT(VARChar(20) , @Date),2))

     -- Return function value:
     Return @Format
End
```

How to use the above function:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_FormatDate](getdate(),'yyyy-mmm-dd')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetDateName (
@date Date
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @result VARCHAR(MAX)

  SELECT @result = Concat(YEAR(@date),'-',CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE())),'-',DAY(@date))
 RETURN @result

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, you can use:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MMMM-dd' ,'en-US')
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to generate the required output using the below query.

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME = Getdate() 
DECLARE @MOD_DATE VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @YEAR VARCHAR(10) 
DECLARE @MONTH VARCHAR(10) 
DECLARE @DAY VARCHAR(10) 

SET @YEAR = Datename(year, @DATE) 
SET @MONTH = Datename(month, @DATE) 
SET @DAY = Datename(day, @DATE) 
SET @MOD_DATE= @YEAR + '-' + LEFT(@MONTH, 3) + '-' + @DAY 

PRINT @MOD_DATE
```

Output:

```
2017-Jun-27
```